# dc.js Scatter Plot with multiple values for a single key

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

We have scatter plots working great in our dashboard, but we have been thrown a curve ball.  We have a new dataset that provides multiple y values for a single key. We have other datasets were this occurs but we had flatten the data first, but we do not want to flatten this dataset.

The scatter plot should us the uid for the x-axis and each value in the inj field for the y-axis values.  The inj field will always be an array of numbers, but each row could have 1 .. n values in the array.

```
var data = [
    {"uid":1, "actions": {"inj":[2,4,10], "img":[10,15,25], "res":[15,19,37]},
    {"uid":2, "actions": {"inj":[5,8,15], "img":[5,8,12],   "res":[33, 45,57]}
    {"uid":3, "actions": {"inj":[9],      "img":[2],        "res":[29]}
];
```

We can define the dimension and group to plot the first value from the inj field.

```
var ndx   = crossfilter(data);
var spDim = ndx.dimension(function(d){ return [d.uid, d.actions.inj[0]];});
var spGrp = spDim.group();
```

But are there any suggestions on how to define the scatter plot to handle multiple y values for each x value?

[image]

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/woolycew65/a7uwbo0u/) example showing how I can display the first element or the last element.  But how can I show all elements of the array?

**--- Additional Information ---**

Above is just a simple example to demonstrate a requirement.  We have developed a dynamic data explorer that is fully data driven.  Currently the datasets being used are protected.  We will be adding a public dataset soon to show off the various features.  Below are a couple of images.

I have hidden some legends.  For the Scatter Plot we added a vertical only brush that is enabled when pressing the "Selection" button. The notes section is populated on scatter plot chart initialization with the overall dataset statistics.  Then when any filter is performed the notes section is updated with statistics of just the filtered data.

[image: Explorer Charts]

The field selection tree displays the metadata for the selected dataset.  The user can decide which fields to show as charts and in datatables (not shown).  Currently for the dataset shown we only have 89 available fields, but for another dataset there are 530 fields the user can mix and match.

[image: Chart Field Selection]

I have not shown the various tabs below the charts DIV that hold several datatables with the actual data.

The metadata has several fields that are defined to help use dynamically build the explorer dashboard.

Comment: Hrrrmmm, I remember some issues around this, but [none](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/scatter.html) of the [examples](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/scatter-brushing.html) that are [included](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/splom.html) with dc.js seem to have trouble with this, so I'm having trouble remembering what's wrong. Can you create a fiddle or similar?

Comment: Oh I guess this boils down to creating a fake group which can turn a single row of data into multiple inputs for the scatter plot. It's not specifically to do with multiple y values for an x value. You'll be happier if you can flatten your data, but a fake group is possible.

Comment: I have added a jsFiddle example to the post.

Comment: I am looking into it. One caveat: crossfilter can only filter by the rows in the data given to it, so you won't be able to do rectangular selection, only horizontal selection by UID. Changing the brush might be tricky; first I'll just demonstrate getting the input to work with a fake group.

Answer (score 1):

I warned you the code would not be pretty! You will probably be happier if you can flatten your data, but it's possible to make this work.

We can first aggregate all the `inj`s within each `uid`, by filtering by the rows in the data and aggregating by `uid`. In the reduction we count the instances of each `inj` value:

```
        uidDimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
            return +d.uid;
        }),
        uidGroup = uidDimension.group().reduce(
            function(p, v) { // add
                v.actions.inj.forEach(function(i) {
                    p.inj[i] = (p.inj[i] || 0) + 1;
                });
                return p;
            },
            function(p, v) { // remove
                v.actions.inj.forEach(function(i) {
                    p.inj[i] = p.inj[i] - 1;
                    if(!p.inj[i])
                        delete p.inj[i];
                });
                return p;
            },
            function() { // init
                return {inj: {}};
            }
        );
        uidDimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
            return +d.uid;
        }),
        uidGroup = uidDimension.group().reduce(
            function(p, v) { // add
                v.actions.inj.forEach(function(i) {
                    p.inj[i] = (p.inj[i] || 0) + 1;
                });
                return p;
            },
            function(p, v) { // remove
                v.actions.inj.forEach(function(i) {
                    p.inj[i] = p.inj[i] - 1;
                    if(!p.inj[i])
                        delete p.inj[i];
                });
                return p;
            },
            function() { // init
                return {inj: {}};
            }
        );
```

Here we assume that there might be rows of data with the same `uid` and different `inj` arrays. This is more general than needed for your sample data: you could probably do something simpler if there is indeed only one row of data for each `uid`.

To flatten out the resulting group, with  we can use a ["fake group"](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups) to create one group-like `{key, value}` data item for each `[uid, inj]` pair:

```
    function flatten_group(group, field) {
        return {
            all: function() {
                var ret = [];
                group.all().forEach(function(kv) {
                    Object.keys(kv.value[field]).forEach(function(i) {
                        ret.push({
                            key: [kv.key, +i],
                            value: kv.value[field][i]
                        });
                    })
                });
                return ret;
            }
        }
    }
    var uidinjGroup = flatten_group(uidGroup, 'inj');
```

[image: scatter plot]

[Fork of your fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/Lt3jxwL7/)

In the fiddle, I've added a bar chart to demonstrate filtering by UID. Filtering on the bar chart works, but filtering on the scatter plot does not. If you need to filter on the scatter plot, that could probably be fixed, but it could only filter on the `uid` dimension because your data is too course to allow filtering by `inj`.

Comment: If you wanted brushing to work on the scatter plot, it would need to be a horizontal brush like the bar chart has, not rectangular selection. I'd be happy to figure that out but I thought I'd post this first.

Comment: Wow, very impressed. I have added additional information to my initial post that begins to detail how this requirement fits into the larger picture. **Note:**  There is only one row of data for each UID because it is the unique identifier for each row in the dataset.  I think I could make this work dynamically in our code, but I will need to make it work with our scatter plot vertical only brush.

Comment: I added a PieChart (using a new field [gender]) and changed the injCountGroup to use uidDimension2 and not uidDimension. When I filter the scatter plot vertically (fully side to side) but only selecting the dot at y-axis 15 it does not depict the correct data in the pie chart (1 male, 0 female). Arg!!  [jsfiddle fork](https://jsfiddle.net/woolycew65/beexr7yn/)

Comment: One male is correct, right? It's selecting UID 4. To my surprise, there is a special case in the 2D filter used by the scatter plot, where if the data it is checking is scalar, it compares only the X coordinate. So I guess this works intentionally, although normally I wouldn't expect to be able to filter a 1D dimension with a 2D brush.

Comment: It might be possible to force the brush to display as 1D, which would be a lot more clear in this scenario. But I haven't looked into it yet.