# HeatMap dc.js - Displaying the Top 10 columns

Tags: heatmap, dc.js

I'm working on heatmap using dc.js. I'm having trouble displaying the top 10 columns. Here is an example of my heatmap below.

[image: HeatMap Example]

Notice that there are too many columns. I'm trying to display the top 10 columns. For example,
column 5 has the highest total amount of items (a+b+c+d+e+f+h+i+j). Then column 10 has the second highest total amount of items and so on.

Is there a way to display that in heatmap dc.js? Is this possible? This took me days to figure out and I'm all out of ideas. Here is my code below.

```
        chart
        .width(900)
        .height(400)
        .margins({top: 10, right: 0, bottom: 50, left: 70})
        .dimension(dimension)
        .group(group)
        .keyAccessor(function(d) { return d.key[0]; })
        .valueAccessor(function(d) { return d.key[1]; })
        .colorAccessor(function(d) { return d.value; })
        .title(function(d){
            })
        .colors(["#ccc","#edf8b1","#c7e9b4","#7fcdbb","#41b6c4","#1d91c0","#225ea8","#253494","#081d58"])
         .data(function (d) {
            return d.order(function (d) {
                return d;
            }
            ).top(10);
        })    
        ;
```

The rest of my heatmap code is just displaying the column labels and onclick features, etc.

Sorry if my code is messy after the `.colors()` function. I was trying to understand the `.data()` and how to make it the top 10. Apparently it gets the highest total for only specific row and column but not the complete total of a column.

Answer (score 1):

#### Using a filter

If you're willing to filter all the data (including any other charts based on this crossfilter), I think the easiest way to do a top ten is to create another dimension on the columns, and then use a group to determine the top ten, and filter based on that.

I've built a fiddle demonstrating this technique, [based on the standard heatmap example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/heat.html).

First we need a dimension based on the columns (in this case "runs"):

```
var runDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return +d.Run; }),
```

We'll then create a group which sums up all the values (in this case "speeds") in each column:

```
    runTotalGroup = runDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {
       return +d.Speed;
    });
```

Fetch the top ten keys in this group:

```
var topTen = runTotalGroup.top(10).map(kv => kv.key);
```

And filter the dimension based on these keys:

```
runDim.filter(function(k) {
    return topTen.indexOf(k) !== -1;
});
```

We also need to remove any empty bins from the heatmap, and we can use a [fake group from the FAQ](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups) for that:

```
function remove_empty_bins(source_group) {
    return {
        all:function () {
            return source_group.all().filter(function(d) {
                //return Math.abs(d.value) > 0.00001; // if using floating-point numbers
                return d.value !== 0; // if integers only
            });
        }
    };
}

chart
    .group(remove_empty_bins(runExptGroup))
```

[Here is the fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/qx39gfbn/12/)

The big caveat with this approach, as I mentioned above, is that this will filter the data for all charts on this crossfilter. It's also inflexible - the top ten might change based on other filters changing, but we've just taken a snapshot and won't see those changes.

Doing this "the right way" would require aggregating the data a different way and/or a more complex fake group. Ping me if this solution doesn't work for you, and I'll think about it some more.

#### Using elaborate fake groups

If you want to do this the right way, without applying extra filters, you'll need to twist the data a few different ways.

First, we'll reduce the data by column. Then we'll sort by total, and finally flatten the columns back into the x/y bins that the heatmap expects. And after that, we still need to tell the heatmap how to order the columns!

But, first, let's make sure that all our data is numbers, not strings. Doing aggregations on strings can lead to nasty results.

```
experiments.forEach(function(d) {
    d.Run = +d.Run;
    d.Expt = +d.Expt;
    d.Speed = +d.Speed;
});
```

Here is three-way data twister (I warned you!):

```
function flatten_group(group, field) { // step 3
    return {
        all: function() {
            var ret = [];
            group.all().forEach(function(kv) {
                Object.keys(kv.value[field]).forEach(function(i) {
                    ret.push({
                        key: [kv.key, +i],
                        value: kv.value[field][i]
                    });
                });
            });
            return ret;
        }
    };
}
function reduce_second_dimension(dim, dimfield, valfield) {
    var group1 = dim.group().reduce( // step 1
        function(p, v) { // add
            p.second[v[dimfield]] = (p.second[v[dimfield]] || 0) + v[valfield];
            return p;
        },
        function(p, v) { // remove
            p.second[v[dimfield]] = p.second[v[dimfield]] - v[valfield];
            return p;
        },
        function() {
            return {second: {}};
        }
    );
    return flatten_group({
        all: function() { // step 2
            var _all = group1.all().slice();
            _all.forEach(function(kv) {
                kv.value.total = d3.sum(Object.keys(kv.value.second), 
                                        function(k) { return kv.value.second[k]; });
            });
            _all.sort(function(a, b) {
                return b.value.total - a.value.total;
            });
            return _all;
        }
    }, 'second');
}
```

It could probably be modularized better, but the three steps are

1. group and reduce by column, creating a key/value mapping for each row within each column
2. sort the columns by their totals
3. break the key/value mapping in each reduced column out into multiple col/row bins. (From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47934744/dc-js-scatter-plot-with-multiple-values-for-a-single-key?rq=1).)

The heatmap still will try to sort the data, so we need to tell it the column order, every time it starts processing the data:

```
function apply_keyorder() {
    var xkeyorder = {}, j = 0;
    runExptGroup.all().forEach(function(kv) {
        if(xkeyorder[kv.key[0]] === undefined) {
            xkeyorder[kv.key[0]] = j++;
        }
    });
    chart.colOrdering((a,b) => xkeyorder[a] - xkeyorder[b]);
}
chart.on('preRender', apply_keyorder);
chart.on('preRedraw', apply_keyorder);
```

It might be simpler to use `.cols()` than `.colOrdering()` - this is what I saw first.

I've run out of time to explain this further: [here's the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/34ssc6dg/16/)!

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have multiple charts that are using the same data spreadsheet. If i do that approach, would it automatically filter all other charts when loading a page? No worries on the empty bins. We want to see which rows for a column that have empty bins. Plus I added a feature that it will not filter if there empty bins (or items equals to 0).

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem with this approach - it will filter all the charts by the top ten columns - that's what `runDim.filter( ....` does. I think it's possible to just modify the data for the chart but that's more complicated.

Comment: Is there a way to sort the columns by descending order base on the total of the columns and display the first 10 columns? That approach i was trying to do that but it didnt work or maybe i did it wrong. Would that be possible?

Comment: It's pretty much the same problem, since the sort is unrelated to the shape of the data, which heat map expects in `{key: [x,y], value}` pairs. It's definitely doable, will just take a little thought what the best way is.

Comment: Is it possible to choose specific columns to display? I got the top 10 list by doing the var topTen = runTotalGroup.top(10).map(kv => kv.key); I can see which are the top ten and i can use that list to display it. Not sure which heatmap api to use, but i could try to loop the list and return the columns that is equal to any from the list. I tried using .cols(..) but its displaying funny. Any suggestion which api to use to manually display specific columns in the heatmap?

Comment: I don't know about that, I'm sticking with the original question. I've added another section above.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. What i did was..

Grab the top 10 using the crossfilter() library.

```
var runDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return +d.Run; }),
    runTotalGroup = runDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {
       return +d.Speed;
    });
var topTen = runTotalGroup.top(10).map(kv => kv.key);
```

Once I grab the only top ten of the list, then in the heatmap chart, work on the .data(...) function. This is where you manually displaying the data using for loop and if statements. Its tricky but once I understand how the data is formatted in heatmap, then I can manually display the data without filtering all other dc charts. AND the crossfiltering works!